# Get a DataTable To Tuple List using a for loop

Tags: c#, .net, database

so I am getting data from a Database and i need the data in  a tuple list however the data i am unable to get it into a tuple to put it in the list.

```
List<Tuple<string,decimal,char>> results = new List< Tuple<string, decimal, char>>() ;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        OpenDBConnection.

        using (var comm = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            GETDATA();
        }



        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            object value = table.Rows[0].ItemArray[col.Ordinal];

        }

        CloseConnection()

        return results;
```

some how i need to get value into a tuple and then into the list however i have not found a way online to be able to do such a thing.

Comment: You sould use the foreach to fetch the rows, not columns, then you create the tuple geting the values from the respective column. Then just add it to the list

Comment: @Magnetron how would you add it to a tuple with out declaration all i get is errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example with data:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("C1",typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("C2",typeof(decimal));
table.Columns.Add("C3",typeof(char));

for(int i = 65; i < 65 + 10; i++)
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row[0] = "string"+i.ToString();
    row[1] = i;
    row[2] = (char)i;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

List<Tuple<string, decimal, char>> results = new List< Tuple<string, decimal, char>>();

foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
{
    var tup = Tuple.Create((string)r[0], (decimal)r[1], (char)r[2]);
    results.Add(tup);
}
```

it results:

```
Item1    Item2  Item3
string65    65  A
string66    66  B
string67    67  C
string68    68  D
string69    69  E
string70    70  F
string71    71  G
string72    72  H
string73    73  I
string74    74  J
```